# Why does UPDATE x SET y='c' AND TRUE result in y='0'

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-injection

I'm playing around with an SQL challenge and noticed that given a table `x` with a single `TEXT` column `y` the following query:

`UPDATE x SET y='c' AND TRUE`

results in `y='0'`

Also:

`UPDATE x SET y='c' OR TRUE`

results in `y='1'`

Out of curiosity I'm trying to understand what's happening underneath to produce these results.

Comment: `'c' AND TRUE` is nothing but mysql internally will try to convert the string to  integer and hence it becomes `0 and true` which is `1` now if you try on mysql terminal as `select '1 c' and true` the first string conversion would give `1` and `1 and true` is `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions `y='c' AND TRUE` and `y='c' OR TRUE` are [*Boolean expressions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression). They evaluate to either `1` when the expression is true, or to `0`, when the expression is false.

Your `update` evaluates these expressions, and stores their results back in the field `y`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that it was treated as a boolean expression but what I was more unsure of is why 'c' == 0

Comment: Close, but the point is that 'c' is first cast to double *before* boolean expression is evaluated. The fact that 'c' fails to cast to proper *double* throws a warning and returns zero which is used for boolean evaluation.

Comment: That's also the reason why `'2' AND TRUE` evaluates to TRUE while `'X' AND TRUE` is false. This is due to the fact that `'2'` is valid double and therefore non-zero (i.e. TRUE) when cast to boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Because what actually happens is:

```
UPDATE x SET y=('c' AND TRUE)
```

and

```
UPDATE x SET y=('c' OR TRUE)
```

and `'c'` evaluates to `0` as a boolean

Comment: Thanks. Do all chars and strings evaluate to 0 as boolean? Is there anyway to get another result?

Comment: Strings get evaluated to an integer, because there is no actual boolean in MySQL. Those which don't begin with digits will evaluate to 0, otherwise to the appropriate integer. Non-zero integers are interpreted as true in a boolean context. E.g: 'abc1234' -> false, '1234abc' -> true, '0123' -> true, 'true' -> false ...